# PageRank computation as the left principal eigenvector

Tags: python, numpy

I'm following the book here to compute PageRank: http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/markov-chains-1.html

I built the transition matrix P as indicated in the book. Then I computed the PageRank scores by raising the transition matrix P to higher powers, as said in the book. To make sure my computations are correct I followed this example: http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/the-pagerank-computation-1.html

The transition matrix is:

```
P = np.array([[1./6, 2./3, 1./6], 
              [5./12, 1./6, 5./12],
              [1./6, 2./3, 1./6]])
```

The results of the PageRank scores are the following (by computing P^40):

```
[0.28, 0.44, 0.28]
```

as in the book.

But the book also says that one can find the PageRank scores by computing the principal left eigenvector of the transition matrix P. So I tried this with numpy:

```
v, V = np.linalg.eig(P.T)
left_vec = V[:, 0].T
print left_vec
```

and I got:

```
[-0.46829291 -0.74926865 -0.46829291]
```

so what's wrong?!

Comment: you need to normalize it. left_vec / sum(left_vec) gives: array([ 0.27777778,  0.44444444,  0.27777778])

Comment: Note also that, according to the `np.linalg.eig` [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html): "the eigenvalues are not necessarily ordered", so the proper way would be something like: `left_vec = V[:, v.argmax()]; left_vec /= left_vec.sum()`